# PHP Session Data will Print, but Disappears for Anything Else

Tags: php, session, echo

I have a Session that stores data for a user when they login, but I can only print the data.  Like so...

```
echo print_r($_SESSION);
```

WILL RETURN...

> Array ([user_id] => 5 [access_level] => 4 [user_name] => user1 [division] => NEB [dept] => ALL) 1

But when I enter code like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table where division = '".$_SESSION['division']."' ORDER BY status";
```

And do an echo of that statement, it looks like this...

> SELECT * FROM table where division = '' ORDER BY status

Unless I echo the session variable, the session data disappears!

Please advise.

Comment: is `$SESSION` a typo?  Post your code and maybe we can help.

Comment: Are you sure that you did the session_start(); ?

Comment: Yes, it was an has been corrected.  Good looking out, TW.

Comment: Thanks Erman, the session_start was missing from a header php file.

Comment: If session_start was missing, how could `print_r()` print it correctly? Are those two statements in different scripts?

Comment: No, the echo print_r() worked on the page without the session_start(), so I didn't understand how it could display the variable but call it blank within 2 lines of code(regardless of order).

Comment: @FroNuff You are wellcome. I didn't make an answer because I was't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE division = '{$_SESSION['division']}' ORDER BY status";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to do it like this

```
$division = $_SESSION['division'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table where division = '$division' ORDER BY status";
```

Surprising but it will work.